# What is faster if statement or set?

Tags: java, if-statement, setter

I want to set a property to an other property that could be null. I wonder what is faster, to wrap it around an `if` statement or simply just set the property without the check.

#### with if statement

```
 if (foo.getName() != null) {
         bar.setFoo(foo.getName());
    }
```

#### simple

```
bar.setFoo(foo.getName()); //getName() can be null
```

Comment: Those do *different things*. So it really depends on whether you want to call `bar.setFoo` with `null`.

Comment: Unless you're running this code millions upon millions of times in a tight loop, it's extremely unlikely to matter. Don't spend time optimizing what is unlikely to be a bottleneck. Wait for bottlenecks and then spend time on them.

Comment: If it doesn't make a difference to your code to check for null then go without if check

Comment: I second @T.J.Crowder in that you are pre-optimizing. Write the code in the most clear and readable way - that is almost always more important than eking out nanoseconds (unless you work in HFT or something, in which case go right ahead). That said, an "if" is probably faster than a setter. I would imagine that is the comparison between a simple branch check, versus a method entry and value setting. But again, it's likely negligible.

Comment: Technically, adding the if condition takes a little longer. However, in this case, "a little" is insignificant (a couple of nanoseconds, maybe). Instead of worrying about micro-optimizations like this, you should determine whether *null* is even a valid value for bar.foo. If it isn't, then skipping the if-statement isn't an optimization at all - it's actually a bug.

Comment: I just ran both instances 1 billion times and here are the results:
`No-Null-Check test result = 580 milliseconds`

`Null-Check-If-Statement test result = 674 milliseconds`

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to setFoo() either way, you might as well just set it and skip the condition. I would use the condition if you wanted to take an action if !null and a different action if null.

Answer (score 0):

when `foo.getName() != null` would return `true`, the setter would be called, so you will have 2 commands that will be executed, however the second example will execute only 1 command. I think the second one is more performant

Comment: I think OP might be concerned of a scenario where foo.getName is highly likely to be null, in which case the execution will not only evaluate the if condition, and not the setter. If the "if" is faster than the "set" and he runs this in a world where the condition is always false, the first command could be more performant.